# Converting a REG file to code

Tags: windows, gratis, software-development, .net, visual-studio

I have a Windows Registry file (.REG), which is entered into the Registry when being double clicked.

Now I want to achieve the same result in code with C#. Is there a tool which could convert the REG file into valid C# code doing the same?

I know I could simply keep the REG file and run `regedit /s <file>.reg`, so it's basically a one-liner. The point is that I need to adapt the code so it does slightly different things in different circumstances. Basically I want my application to do it, not with Regedit.

It should:

- open Registry keys for writing
- create keys
- create REG_DWORD, REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ
- put the objects into `using()` constructs
- support Registry deletion syntax
- ideally writes "clean" code, i.e. introduces variables for long substrings

It would be nice if it's a Visual Studio plugin, but any other solution is probably ok, too, because it will only be used once per REG file.

I have tried:

- [reg-to-csharp](http://moser96.github.io/reg-to-csharp/), but it cannot deal with REG_DWORD and REG_EXPAND_SZ, does not dispose the objects, creates subkeys instead of values, does not support delete syntax
- [reg-to-csharp](https://github.com/WelliSolutions/reg-to-csharp) makes a few fixes, but still has no REG_EXPAND_SZ support, does not dispose objects nor support delete syntax

Comment: My [WinPrefs](https://github.com/Tatsh/winprefs) project does conversion from the registry to C, C#, `reg add` commands and PowerShell. So theoretically you could import your reg file then run `path2reg FULL:\PATH\TO\KEY`